# How can I detect Escape key pressed in NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have Created Simple **cocoa** app. In which I use **NSOutlineView**. Now my task is to get the event of Escape Key pressed. In my **appdelegate.m** I implemented all require method for **NSOutlineView**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SubClass your NSOutlineView and capture its key down event as:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{       
    switch([theEvent keyCode]) 
    {
        case 53: // esc
            NSLog(@"ESC");
            // Implement the functionality you want when esc is pressed

            break;

        default:
           [super keyDown:theEvent];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx. I know this way by sub classing the nsoutlineview. But I want do with Appdelegate.m only. I also tried with NSControlTextDidChangeNotification. This gives me escape event when textfield is not blank. All in vain when textfield is empty/blank.

Comment: In that case you may try by registering a global keydown event, check if the key pressed is Esc and your application is front most. And if yes, then implement your functionality.

Comment: You may register for global key event as: [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *event){//your code here}];

Comment: Thanxx. But Its better to do iPhone Programming than mac programming. At least google provide lots of options to apply on problem. Mac programming has limited resources for newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can find out the whther escape key was pressed or not try below one line and used in your method where it is required:-

```
NSUInteger flags = [theEvent keycode];
//After that 

If (flags==53)
{

NSlog(@"Escape key pressed");
}
```